# google maps in java application

Tags: java, google-maps, geolocation

I have to create a java application that display an interactive map (like google maps) and when the user click on a point on the map I have to get the coordinates of the point clicked. I also have to add a bookmark to the map.

I thought to open a web browser in my application and display google maps but I don't know if it's possible and if I can add more bookmarks.
Is also there any free service of maps to do this?

Thank you and excuse for my english :D

Comment: "open a web browser in my application and display google maps but I don't know if it's possible". It is possible. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html for example

Comment: but I'm using Swing and I don't want to open an external program but i have to open a web browser in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved! I'll use the [unfolding library](http://unfoldingmaps.org/) to create the interactive map